# Unexpected elseif... what is wrong with this code?

Tags: php, if-statement

Sorry guys, although there are related questions already on the forums, none of them seem to apply to my situation.  Apparently there is something wrong with this syntax, but I can't spot it.  I've been messing around with it for awhile and no luck.  I guess it has something to do with trying to determine the value of my variable?  Here is the code...

```
<?php if( $page == 'Who We Are' ) { echo 'nothing works'; } ?>
<?php elseif( $page == 'Leadership' ) { echo 'please help'; } ?>
<?php else { echo 'this doesnt matter, because it never gets to this point!'; } ?>
```

The $page variable is dynamically set to display the page title, and print_r confirms that it is returning the title correctly.  Any clue?

Comment: Why are you opening and closing PHP tags on every line?

Comment: Partly because in the actual code I will have html inserted between alternatives.  The code above is just a very simplified version of the code that wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug in the PHP interpreter that will never be fixed. PHP expects any alternatives in an 'if' statement to come immediately next to the closing brace of the statement they apply to. What you are effectively saying here is:

```
START_PHP_PROCESSOR()
if (mystatement == 'mycheck') dosomething();
END_PHP_PROCESSOR()
START_PHP_PROCESSOR()
elseif (mystatement == 'mycheck2') dosomething2();
END_PHP_PROCESSOR
```

Interrupting the parser is confusing it here. It can't figure out where the 'if' it is supposed to be attaching to is.

The best (and, perhaps, ugliest) way to solve your problem is to use the documented : (colon) alternative control block syntax as so:

```
<?php if( $page == 'Who We Are' ): echo 'nothing works'; ?>
<?php elseif( $page == 'Leadership' ): { echo 'please help'; } ?>
<?php else: echo 'this doesnt matter, because it never gets to this point!'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is documented on [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) in the PHP documentation and was designed to make working with control blocks in templates easier.

Comment: SirBrizz and everybody else thank you so much.  For some reason I always just assumed the difference between brackets and colons in conditionals was merely stylistic.  Just to double check your code, should the 2nd line have brackets surrounding the echo statement?  It is working for me without them...

Comment: Good question. I left those in because both "styles" work, however most people do not use braces around conditionals when the alternate control block syntax is used. It's entirely up to you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will address it:

```
<?php if( $page == 'Who We Are' ) {
    echo 'nothing works'; 
}elseif( $page == 'Leadership' ) {
    echo 'please help'; 
}else {
    echo 'this doesnt matter, because it never gets to this point!'; 
} ?>
```

Breaking up the if / elseif with the php tags could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have errors on you'd see something like this errormessage:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in testfile.php on line 3

Basically what it is telling you is that what you have isn't correct php. The cause for this is that you're terminating the first if-statement when you're terminating the php-tag.

So what php sees is:

```
if( $page == 'Who We Are' ) { echo 'nothing works'; } 

//end current if-else control structure
//Below is illegal.
elseif( $page == 'Leadership' ) { echo 'please help'; } 
else { echo 'this doesnt matter, because it never gets to this point!'; }
```

If you want to have an controlstructure that spans over several php-statements i.e `<?php /*code*/ ?>` you should read [this](https://www.php.net/alternative_syntax) and you'd end up with something like this:

```
<?php if( $page == 'Who We Are' ): { echo 'nothing works'; } ?>
<?php elseif( $page == 'Leadership' ): { echo 'please help'; } ?>
<?php else: { echo 'this doesnt matter, because it never gets to this point!'; } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```